# Флаги формата и состояния потоков ввода вывода

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий код, столкнулся с проблемой зацикливания, требуется повторный ввод данных при условии некорректной предыдущей попытки. Как я понимаю, в результате ввода некорректного значения, состояние потока ввода изменяется, что не позволяет вводить новое значение и приводит к зацикливанию.
Не уверен, что все именно так, но в любом случае результата нет, надеюсь на коллективный разум, в чем причина и как исправить, спасибо.

```
void main()
{
    int a = 0;
    bool check = false;

    do {
        while (1) {
            cout << "Vvedite iskomoe znachenie " << endl;
            cin >> a;
            if (a) {
                check = true;
                break;
            } else {
                cout <<
                    "Ohibka prilogenija(vvedeno nedopustimoe znachenie)"
                    << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!check);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот способ точно должен сработать.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    std::ios::iostate state;
    do {
        std::cout << "Input a number" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        state = std::cin.rdstate();
        if (state != std::ios::goodbit) {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear(std::ios::goodbit);
            std::cin.ignore(65535, '\n');
        }
    } while (state != std::ios::goodbit);
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО! Спасибо, а то я уж стал думать, что все, приплыл я.
Такого варианта не знал и не использовал раньше, еще раз спасибо за помощь и науку параллельно, сейчас буду разбирать, что там к чему, и как это все работает, а то чувствую еше не раз пригодится. Удачи, и еще раз спасибо.

Comment: С++ - это здорово!

На C можно просто написать fflush(stdin) , если scanf("%d"...) возвращает 0 (т.е. ошибка в аргументе).

Answer (score 1):

Вложенный цикл `while(1)` ни к чему.

Comment: На счет цикла while(1), это была одна из попыток решить проблему, последняя версия, так сказать, но, тем не менее, даже при его отсутствии ни break, ни continue не решают проблемы, насколько я понимаю, необходимо изменить (вернуть) нормальное состояние потока ввода, но вот, как это сделать, пока не придумал, варианты типа cin.clear(), cin.good() и т.д. результата не принесли.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
int a = 0;
do {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << "Input a number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    if (std::cin.rdstate() != std::ios::goodbit)
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
} while (std::cin.rdstate() != std::ios::goodbit);
```

Все функции и константы - стандартные.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но результат такой же, зацикливание: вывод "Error", "Input a number" и так до послезавтра :)
В отладчике видно, что после первого прохода цикла, при вводе некорректного значения, попытка повтоорного ввода std::cin >> a; просто пропускается, вернее ни к чему не приводит, значение, сохраненное в переменной а, так и остается что-то вроде -85937564846
на каждой итерации и состояние потока соответственно тоже не ахти.

Comment: Что если в начале цикла вызвать std::cin.setstate(std::ios::goodbit);?

Comment: К сожалению все также, варианты по флагам и состояниям первыми пришли в голову, но результата не принесли, я пытался уже изменять саму переменную вручную, как вместе, так и отдельно от потока в начале второй итерации цикла, чтобы попробовать проверять ее, как условие, но она тоже не поддается на уговоры, даже простое присваивание ей другого значения в начале итерации не получается, даже если перед этим (да и после) пытаться изменить состояние потока. Может, просто не помню нужной инструкции для такого случая, а может... не понимаю, что происходит:)